# Find a two dimensional subspace $S^*$ (minimax characterzation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, linear-transformations

Let matrix $A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$. Find a two dimensional subspace
 $S^*$ s.t.

$$\underset{{x \in S^*,\|x\|_2 =1}}  \min  \|Ax\|_2=\underset{{\dim S=2, x \in S},}  \max \underset{{\|x\|_2 =1}}  \min \|Ax\|_2.$$
I'm not sure how to solve this kind of minimax characterization problem. Thanks!

Comment: You could try using the squared $l_2-$ norm. This will probably make computation easier.

Comment: @YukiJ You mean to find the singular value of $\|Ax\|_2$? Since we usually define $\|A\|_2 = \max(x^{H}A^{H}Ax)^{1/2}=\sigma_1 (A)$. Not sure whether this is what you meant.

Comment: Would you mind giving a little bit of more clarification. To my understanding $$\underset{{\|x\|_2 =1}}  \min \|Ax\|_2 = K$$ is a constant. This means $$\underset{{\dim S=2, x \in S}}  \max \underset{{\|x\|_2 =1}}  \min \|Ax\|_2  = \underset{{\dim S=2, x \in S}}  \max K = K$$ is the same constant. Is my reasoning sound?

Comment: @SlavenGlumac Ok? But how do you find the subspace?

Comment: At https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Applications_of_the_SVD there is a section titled Total least squares. Your problem is very similar except you have to take two least singular values.